# Problema con element.innerHTML+=

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Tengo este intento de galeria de imagenes con bootstrap, pero no logro que aparezca bada, este es el codigo completo de la galeria, las imagenes estan nombradas por numeros.

```
<script>
    var imagenes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    var galeria = Document.getElementById('galeria');

        for(imagen of imagenes){
            galeria.innerHTML +=
            `
            <div class="card">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#id${imagen}">
                    <img src="imgs/galery/${imagen}.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="id${imagen}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <button type="button" class="close mr-2" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>  
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <img src="imgs/galery/${imagen}.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded">
                </div>
            </div>
            `
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Algún error en la consola o algo?

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que te estas pisando el html que añades. La propiedad `innerHTML` lo que hace es añadir el código a la web y no es posible utilizar el `+=`.

Para solucionar esto tendrías que añadir el código a un `String` y después añadirlo con `innerHTML`.

```
<script>
    var imagenes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    var galeria = Document.getElementById('galeria');
    var html = "";

        for(imagen of imagenes){
            html +=
            `
            <div class="card">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#id${imagen}">
                    <img src="imgs/galery/${imagen}.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="id${imagen}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <button type="button" class="close mr-2" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>  
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <img src="imgs/galery/${imagen}.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded">
                </div>
            </div>
            `
        }
        galeria.innerHTML = html;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Uncaught TypeError: Document.getElementById is not a function",

Cambiando la `D` por `d` a `var galeria = document.getElementById('galeria');` parece funcionar correctamente.

```js
    var imagenes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    var galeria = document.getElementById('galeria');

        for(imagen of imagenes){
            galeria.innerHTML +=
            `
            <div class="card">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#id${imagen}">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=${imagen}" alt="" class="card-img-top">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="id${imagen}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <button type="button" class="close mr-2" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>  
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=${imagen}" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded">
                </div>
            </div>
            `
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div id="galeria"></div>
```